# drupal get count of value of field - is it possible using custom token?

Tags: drupal-7, token

I am trying to build custom token for this purpose using core php filter, I dont whether it is possible or not.

Content type MEMBERS has fields
Name - text field
Location - text field
MemberSNO - integer -

Let say there are 500 members are signed from different location like 'New york', 'Delhi' etc.
When new member is signed, value for MemberSNO is calculated according to location ie if there are 69 members in location 'Delhi' then MemberSNO should become 70.

Is it possible to achieve this using custom token module with drupal core php filter by passing location as parameter(in this case 'Delhi') and get count.

custom token format would be like
[node-field-location:count]

Comment: Custom Dynamic query and display sounds like a use case for Views. The views result could be displayed as a field using EVA module.